# Need help with reflection example from "The Ruby Programming Language"

Tags: ruby, reflection

In this example from *The Ruby Programming Language* (p.270), I'm confused why the `instance_eval` method on the last line of the sample code **defines a class method** called `String.empty`.

Don't you use `class_eval` to define a class method and `instance_eval` when you want to define an instance method?

```
o.instance_eval("@x") # Return the value of o's instance variable @x

# Define an instance method len of String to return string length
String.class_eval("def len; size; end")

# Here's another way to do that
# The quoted code behaves just as if it was inside "class String" and "end"
String.class_eval("alias len size")

# Use instance_eval to define class method String.empty
# Note that quotes within quotes get a little tricky...
String.instance_eval("def empty; ''; end")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Don't you use `class_eval` to define a
>   class method and `instance_eval` when
>   you want to define an instance method?

Unfortunately, it is not as straightforward as that.

First take a closer look at what the examples of `class_eval` are doing. `class_eval` is a method which comes from Ruby's [module class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001650) so can be called on any class or module. When you use `String.class_eval` you are evaluating the given code in the context of the class. i.e. when you write `String.class_eval("def len; size; end")` it's exactly like you reopened the class and typed the code passed to `class_eval` e.g.

```
class String
  def len
    size
  end
end
```

Thus to add a class method using class_eval you would write `String.class_eval("def self.empty; ''; end")` which has the same effect as:

```
class String
  def self.empty
    ''
  end
end
```

`instance_eval` is defined in Ruby's [Object class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000334) so is available on any Ruby object. In the general case it can be used to add a method to a specific instance. e.g. if we have a String `str` and say:

```
str.instance_eval("def special; size; end")
```

Then this will alias `special` to `size` just for `str` but not for any other String object:

```
irb(main):019:0> "other".special
NoMethodError: undefined method `special' for "other":String
        from (irb):19
```

To understand what is going on with String.instance_eval remember that the class String is itself an object (an instance of the class `Class`) and that there is such a singleton instance object of every class defined. When you use `String.instance_eval` you are evaluating the given code in the context of the `String` instance object. i.e. it is equivalent to reopening String's metaclass and typing the code passed e.g.

```
class String
  class << self
    def empty
      ''
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the general theme:

> Use ClassName.instance_eval to define
>   singleton methods.
>
> Use ClassName.class_eval to define
>   instance methods.

This [post](http://bmorearty.wordpress.com/2009/01/09/fun-with-rubys-instance_eval-and-class_eval/) has a very neat explanation, give it a shot...