# instance_eval vs class_eval in module

Tags: ruby

```
class Foo
    include Module.new { class_eval "def lab; puts 'm' end" }

    def lab
      super 
      puts 'c'
    end
end

Foo.new.lab #=> m c
```

========================================================================

```
class Foo
    include Module.new { instance_eval "def lab; puts 'm' end" }

    def lab
      super 
      puts 'c'
    end
end
```

Notice here I changed class_eval to instance_eval

```
Foo.new.lab rescue nil#=> no super class method lab
Foo.lab #=> undefined method lab for Foo class
```

So it seems that including the module neither defined an instance method nor a class method.

Any explanation what's going on here?

This code was tested on ruby 1.8.7 on mac.

Answer (score 10):

First, think of what `include` does. it makes the **instance** methods of the module being included into **instance** methods on the including class. i.e. apart from the fact that your working example uses an anonymous module it is equivalent to:

```
module M1
  def lab
    puts 'm'
  end
end

class Foo
    include M1

    def lab
      super 
      puts 'c'
    end
end
```

Next, think of what `class_eval` does. It evaluates the given code in the context of the class or module. i.e. it's exactly like you reopened the module and typed the code passed to `class_eval`. So `MyModule = Module.new { class_eval "def lab; puts 'm' end" }` is equivalent to

```
module MyModule
  def lab
    puts 'm'
  end
end
```

Hopefully this explains the case that works.

When you use `instance_eval` you are evaluating the code within the context of the receiving object (in this case the instance of module) so `MyMod2 = Module.new { instance_eval "def lab; puts 'm' end" }` is equivalent to

```
module MyMod2
  def MyMod2.lab
    puts 'm'
  end
end
```

i.e. it creates a **module** method which you'd call via `MyMod2.lab` and such methods are not added as instance methods by `include`.

---

*Please note*: this answer borrows a bit of its explanation from an answer I wrote to a [previous question asking about instance_eval vs. class_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388055/need-help-with-reflection-example-from-the-ruby-programming-language/1388160#1388160) relating to an example from *The Ruby Programming Language* book. You might find that answer helpful too.

Comment: excellent explanation. breaking things apart and looking at it one step at a time helps.

Answer (score 3):

including a module just takes the instance methods - you are looking for extend. luckily to get the best of both worlds, you can simply do:

```
module Something
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def blah
      puts "lol"
    end
  end
end

class Test
  include Something
end
```

irb:

```
>> Test.blah
lol
=> nil
```